# How can I order a matrix by another matrix, keeping original numeric value (Using R)

Tags: r

I have searched google a lot, and there were many useful R code solutions in Stackoverflow.
I have two matrices, they are index matrix and real return matrix.
Their dimensions are same (about 500 by 500 matrix?)
They were too big, so I am doing exercise with much smaller example.

```
> setwd("B:/FE/2013.4.28")
> data <- read.csv("ex.csv")
> data
   a  b   c    d  e  f   g    h     i
1  7  5   2    1 11  4   5   55    22
2  3  1   3    5  2  4   6    8    13
3 90 99 999 9999  2 22 222 2223 10973
4  8  4 988 1004  6 15  12   78    50
> id <- t(apply(data,1,order))
> lapply(1:nrow(id),function(i)data[i,id[i,]])
[[1]]
  d c f b g a  e  i  h
1 1 2 4 5 5 7 11 22 55

[[2]]
  b e a c f d g h  i
2 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 8 13

[[3]]
  e  f  a  b   g   c    h    d     i
3 2 22 90 99 222 999 2223 9999 10973

[[4]]
  b e a  g  f  i  h   c    d
4 4 6 8 12 15 50 78 988 1004

> matrix(names(data)[id],ncol=ncol(data))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,] "d"  "c"  "f"  "b"  "g"  "a"  "e"  "i"  "h" 
[2,] "b"  "e"  "a"  "c"  "f"  "d"  "g"  "h"  "i" 
[3,] "e"  "f"  "a"  "b"  "g"  "c"  "h"  "d"  "i" 
[4,] "b"  "e"  "a"  "g"  "f"  "i"  "h"  "c"  "d" 
> criteria <- matrix(names(data)[id],ncol=ncol(data))
> data2 <- read.csv("ex2.csv",header=TRUE)
> data2
         a       b        c       d       e        f        g       h         i
1 1.100000 1.13000 0.900000 1.70000 1.54500 1.220000 2.000000 1.40000 1.9800000
2 1.242300 1.64345 1.452500 2.20000 1.43240 0.234423 1.556234 1.32432 1.2342300
3 1.542542 1.35432 1.342523 1.23432 1.43254 1.324320 1.546540 2.43200 0.4321432
4 1.542354 1.65460 0.324130 0.65460 1.23452 1.654325 1.342134 0.34124 1.1000000
> rr <- order(data2,criteria)
> matrix(rr,ncol=ncol(criteria))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]   22   16    5   20   28   18    3    6   33
[2,]   12    9   21    2   11   19   17   24   25
[3,]   32    1   34   23    7   10   27    8   14
[4,]   35   36   15   30   29    4   26   13   31
```

This was my code. I have set 'ex' as index matrix, and ex2 as real return matrix. 
I wanted to re-order 'ex' ascending row by row (each row means the index(criteria) number in one week)

Then, my definite goal is re-ordering 'matrix ex2' as 'matrix ex'

I had copied and pasted lapply code in stackoverflow. So I could re-order 'matrix ex' like this.

```
> matrix(names(data)[id],ncol=ncol(data))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,] "d"  "c"  "f"  "b"  "g"  "a"  "e"  "i"  "h" 
[2,] "b"  "e"  "a"  "c"  "f"  "d"  "g"  "h"  "i" 
[3,] "e"  "f"  "a"  "b"  "g"  "c"  "h"  "d"  "i" 
[4,] "b"  "e"  "a"  "g"  "f"  "i"  "h"  "c"  "d" 

> rr <- order(data2,criteria)
> matrix(rr,ncol=ncol(criteria))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]   22   16    5   20   28   18    3    6   33
[2,]   12    9   21    2   11   19   17   24   25
[3,]   32    1   34   23    7   10   27    8   14
[4,]   35   36   15   30   29    4   26   13   31
```

data was ex, data2 was ex2.
d was header of smallest number in row 1(=1), h was header of largest number in row 1(=55)
Therefore, I have succeeded at making ex ordered ascending, row by row. ex was re-ordered row by row. It was presented by headers. I could do this with copy-and paste the code on Stackoverflow.

So, I want to re-order ex2 using the order of ex.
Then, I could get only this results. Function 'order' shows me that 22nd number in matrix ex2  was smallest in ex2.

But, I have two problem.
First problem is that "I want to re-order ex2 on ex, row by row". My result was ordered, but was not ordered row by row, 
Second problem was that " I want to know the numeric value of ex2, not the rank", My result was showing me the rank of matrix elements.

How can I get ordered ex2 as the order of ex, using row by row method?

I'm not good at English, I'm sorry for my poor English.
Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  Your question is a bit confusing.  There are many matricies shown and it is hard to follow.  Perhaps consider editing your question to something more basic:  `"I have matrix 1 that is <this> and matrix 2 that is <that>. I would like to order matrix 1 by matrix 2 so that the result looks like matrix 3 <here>" `

Comment: Also, if you are sorting by row, can you please define how you determine the order between two rows?  (ie, which row goes first, which row goes second? how does one know?).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `order` the rows of `ex2` according to rows of `ex`,

```
idx = t(apply(ex, 1, order))

t(sapply(1:nrow(idx), function(i) ex2[i,][idx[i,]]))
```